# Drupal View to show nodequeue and another category

Tags: drupal, view, nodequeue

In Drupal, I am trying to build a view that shows both items in my nodequeue of type cat1, and all items of type cat2. The nodequeue works fine by adding a relationship, but I can't find out how to combine this with my cat2 items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a `Content: Type` filter for cat2
- Select `And/Or Rearrange` in the drop-down beside `Filter Criteria`
- `Create new filter group`*
- Move your nodequeue and content type filters into the new group
- Select the `Or` operator for this new group
- Make sure the operator between the two filter groups is set to `And`

** This is assuming you have a `Content: Published` filter set that would always apply.*